# Use array to post html form with every aray value ony by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I am wondering if the folowing is possible.

I fetch a list of names as an array from a SQL database. I need all those names to be posted with a html form one by one. This action should be activated with one button. When the button is clicked the names should be posted one by one untill all names are posted, then stop. So probebly jquery or javascript is needed but that is new for me. I have been searching but I can not find anything that can help me accomplisch this.

I am sorry for asking this question and my language (english is not my main language) but I don't know if this is even possible and I cant find any corresponding topics while researching..

PS: I can not use Ajax for the post !!

Example to get the names:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM example WHERE examplefield = 1");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); //only works when nd_mysli is set on the server!

    while ($rowid = $result->fetch_assoc())
{

    $arrayusername[] = $rowid['username'];
    }
```

I need all the names from the `$arrayusername[]` to be posted with below form one by one by pressing the following button

```
<input type="button" value="Post all names one by one" 
onClick="sendallvalues('???') "class="example_c" />
```

// The button should do the following post name 1, end. post name 2 end, post name 3 end. stop script when all names are posted.

```
    <form method="post" target="_example" action="https://www.example.nl">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?= $arrayusername[] ?>"  name="postvalue" >
        </form>
```

// should be hidden to the user and is only ment for the name atrribute to have a place ! All the stuff needs to happen by pressing that one button !

```
       <script>
        function sendallvalues(???) {
        //I have no Idea where to begin to make this happen.. But it should post the form one by one with one value at the time untill all names are posted.

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: No one that can help?:(

Comment: I try to help you. I think you need a for loop for creating the input hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can explain more detailed what you need.
The value attribute should have one name and you create different input fields.

```php
<form method="post" target="_example" action="https://www.example.nl">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $arrayusername[] ?>"  name="postvalue" >
    <input class="example_s"  type="submit" value="Post name">
</form>
```

should be

```php
<?php

$arrayusername = array('Name1','Name2');

echo '<form method="post" target="_example" action="https://www.example.nl">';

   foreach ($arrayusername as $key => $value) {
      echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $value .'" name="name-' . $key . '" >';
   } 

      echo'<input class="example_s"  type="submit" value="Post name">';
echo '</form>'
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help allready. I simply need the values to be posted automaticly when the user clicks on the button. This needs to he one by one because of the restriction on post when sending multiple post requests.

Comment: Hmm see what you might mean. The forms itself dont need to he able to generate individualy. Only the input name needs to he posted one by one when clicking the button send all. Wrong example on my part. Stronger yet in production i need them hidden. I am searching for a way to send all the values one by one with post method while using one button. So one click should send 10 names one by one. As if then forms where there and you click them as user one by one to submit the value

Comment: If i understand correctly your code creates forms with buttons times the array names. That is not what i need ! Sorry for confusing you

Comment: I updated the question. I hope it is more clear now ?